# How every browser handle caching after query string has been removed in file location

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, caching, browser, opera

Please consider this situation:

First: a file with static location (without any query string) loaded in browser like this example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/style.css">
```

Second: We change content of this file and address it with some query string like the following example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/style.css?ver=2">
```

If we address this file without any query string again (same as first example), how each browser (like: Firefox, Chrome, IE, ...) will load this file?

1. It's uses unmodified cache (first example)
2. It's uses modified cache (second example)
3. It's try to reload the file

Please answer with certainty.

The goal of my question is:

> Are browsers handling queried files as a new file, updated file or same as
>   the original?

Comment: I noticed today that chrome on mobile is caching my page if it has a query parameter or if it doesn’t have one. Need to work out if it is my ISP